# How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Info_instrumental` (
  `id_instrument` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `instrument` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `exp_ins` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `User_name_user` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_instrument`, `User_name_user` `)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_Info_instrumental_User1_idx` (`User_name_user` ` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Info_instrumental_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`User_name_user`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Usuario` (`name_user`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I  want to increment my id field like '001','002','003'.... How can i do this using a trigger?

I want something like this :

```
| id_instrument | instrument| exp_ins | User_name_user
------------------------------------------------------
|      001     | guitar    | 2 years |   Marcus
|      002     | piano     | 6 months|   Leo
```

Comment: `int` values do not have leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zerofill` keyword in your create table to see the result you are seeking. Here's an example:

```
mysql> create table info_instrumental (
     >     id_instrument int(3) zerofill not null primary key auto_increment
     > );

mysql> insert into info_instrumental values (1), (2), (3);

mysql> select * from info_instrumental;
+---------------+
| id_instrument |
+---------------+
|           001 |
|           002 |
|           003 |
+---------------+
```

You won't need a trigger to have a result like this.